# How to remove the cap of a sphere in and chose the side where it cuts

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

How can I remove the cap of a sphere in graphics ?

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 5]}, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
```

I'd like to remove the green part for example here :

[image]

**EDIT** :
After having an answer, I still have a problem when I want to chose the side it must cut. For instance

```
Graphics3D[{Sphere[]}, 
 ClipPlanes -> InfinitePlane[{{0, 1, 0.8}, {2, 0, 0.8}, {0, 0, 0.8}}]]
```

cuts the top. But what if I want to cut the bottom. So I know I could cut at $-0.8$ and return. But if I want to cut the two caps at the top and the bottom how could I proceed ?

Comment: See the first example for [`ClipPlanes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html).

Comment: Have you read through the documentation for `ClipPlanes` as suggested by @JasonB.? The "Neat Examples" section demonstrates how to cut multiple planes – you just have to specify a list of planes to cut.

Comment: You can change the orientation of the plane by permuting points. e.g. `Graphics3D[{Sphere[]}, 
 ClipPlanes -> InfinitePlane[{{2, 0, 0.8}, {0, 1, 0.8}, {0, 0, 0.8}}]]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify `ClipPlanes` as a 4-tuple (or as a list of 4-tuples) to control the directions more conveniently. It is also more convenient to use `ClipPlanes` as a directive (rather than an option) to specify multiple clip planes for a given primitive:

[`ClipPlanes >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html)

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{ClipPlanes -> {{0, 0, -1, .8}, {0, 0, 1, .7}, {1, 1, 1, 1.5}}, 
 Opacity[.7], Sphere[]}, 
 Axes -> True, Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-.7, .8 }}]
```

[image]

Add the option

```
ClipPlanesStyle -> (Opacity[.5, #] & /@ {Red, Blue, Green})
```

to see the three clipping planes:

[image]

**Update:** A function to flip the side that is cut away by a clip plane:

```
ClearAll[flipSide]
flipSide[{a_?NumericQ, b_, c_, d_}] := -{a, b, c, d};
flipSide[ip_InfinitePlane] := MapAt[#[[{2, 1, 3}]] &, ip, {1}];

Graphics3D[{{Red, ClipPlanes -> {{1, 0, 1, -.8}}, Opacity[.7], 
   Sphere[]}, {Green, ClipPlanes -> {flipSide@{1, 0, 1, -.8}}, 
   Opacity[.7], Sphere[]}}, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{{Red, ClipPlanes -> {InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}]}, 
   Opacity[.7], Sphere[]}, 
  {Green, ClipPlanes -> {flipSide@
      InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}]}, Opacity[.7], 
   Sphere[]}}, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]